# High usage on Azure log analytics

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a relatively simple web app set up with a SQL database, and we have log analytics. We have "Auditing" turned on for the SQL server, and for some reason I'm seeing 2.8GB of usage a day just from the AzureDiagnostics table (SQLSecurityAuditEvents category). Looking into the logs, I'm seeing a long list of RPC_COMPLETED events, which isn't listed in the default events that are audited according to Azure. There is an event every 50ms or so, and the statement is "exec sp_execute 34,3143442" (or something very similar).

I've tried searching online and can't find anything about what this could be - but it's making our log analytics pretty expensive. Has anyone else found this and got to the bottom of it?

Comment: Im seeing the same - any ideas?

Comment: Hi @gisWeeper, mine was due to auditing being enabled in Azure. Apparently this logs a huge amount of data and increases the cost a fair bit.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the same problem for me. Auditing was enabled on database and was logging huge amount of data. Upon analysing this data I found some poor code implementation - a number of queries in Entity Framework looping hundreds of time = lots of audits.